# Can my Apple ID password be recovered in Keychain Access?

Tags: macos, keychain

Is it possible to find an Apple ID/iCloud password in Keychain Access? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 5):

2020 note: looks like this is not possible anymore, keychain just stores tokens (encrypted version of password)

Comment: It works for me, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @LillyCham It might have been a while since you changed the password last.

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2-28-2022

Just tried it with macOS 12.2.1 Monterey. Still works.

——-

Yes. This works with Sierra:

Find the utility Keychain Access ( Applications > Utilities) and launch it. If the lock icon at the upper left of the window is locked, unlock it.
Enter "appleid" (no quotes) in the search box at the upper right.
Find "appleid" in the resulting list, and double-click it.
A small window will appear, with tabbed choices for "Attributes" or "Access Control." Make sure "Attributes" is selected. At the bottom left of the Attributes tab, select the box labeled "Show password."
Another dialog will be displayed; enter your computer login, and press "Return."
The Apple ID password should then be displayed.

Comment: This basically works, but in my case it's not the actual password that's displayed, but what appears to be some Base64 encoded value.

Comment: @AlgorithmandBlues Is your computer's HD encrypted? Mine isn't.

Comment: Yes it is, that might explain the different behavior here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is in Keychain Access.

1. Go to Keychain Access and search for "idmsa.apple.com".
2. And then double click and select "Show password" and there you go.

I am on MacOS Catalina Mac 10.15.5.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

It depends.

TL;DR: **no, you cannot get your password from Keychain Access** (at least not for everyone, more explanation below). But there're other ways out if you simply just wanted to regain access to your Apple ID.

### About "Saved Passwords" thingy

If you **actually saved** your Apple ID password into your iCloud Keychain (most likely pressed "Remember" when Safari prompted you to save password after successful login) — then yes, like any other saved password in iCloud Keychain, your Apple ID password can be revealed through **Keychain Access** or **Passwords** preference pane (after macOS Monterey). And the associated site should be `idmsa.apple.com`, `www.icloud.com`, etc.

And because you saved your Apple ID password inside iCloud Keychain, just like passwords for any other sites, this will work no matter what macOS version you're rocking, you can even reveal your password on your iPhone, iPad and iPod touch, as they're iCloud-enabled.

But what if you **didn't** save your Apple ID password in iCloud Keychain? Then sorry, you're out of luck.

### Resetting password through Trusted Devices

You can **reset** your Apple ID password through a trusted device signed in with your Apple ID. More details on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487). But no, you still cannot reveal your current password.

### Your Mac doesn't store your Apple ID password

Unless you saved your Apple ID password into iCloud Keychain, your Mac wouldn't store your Apple ID password **in plain text**, instead, it saves **credentials and access tokens** for a variety of services.

In modern information security architecture, saving password in the form of plain text is considered as a security hazard. In case of data breach, passwords will be leaked directly to attackers. Instead, your password will act as an "original representation", that would be transformed into different representations and forms for different services. So passwords only exist in your mind, not anywhere else.

Unless you saved your password in iCloud Keychain, there'll be no way to reveal your Apple ID password, otherwise it would be a vulnerability. The whole Apple system (so do Google systems, and any other modern technology company) is designed to **not** save password in plain text. And in case you forgot it, you can always reset it, but not reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried 'idmsa.apple.com' as suggested by Adam as the key on my Keychain on my newly upgraded MacBook Pro 12.2.1 Catalina, and my password is there  (once you give keychain your local credentials).

The upgrade did a reboot and the splash screen wanted AppleID info and did not take the password I remembered (felt odd). I clicked 'skip for now' logged in and everything seems fine, went to Keychain and collected the password-but now that I logged in with my local credentials-I don't need it.

(Not enough cred to comment or upvote- since there is conflicting information in this thread so...)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319379)

Answer (score 0):

imdsa.apple.com doesn't always show up in Keychain Access, at least it didn't for me.

If that's happening to you, try a search just for "icloud"

You'll get like a dozen different entries that pull up. Look for the one that is just your username (in my case it's my email address and that's typically the deal). Click on that and then click on Show Password and you should be able to get it that way.